# Android: QLocalServer::listen fails with "Name error"

Tags: android, qt

We can't reproduce this but on some Android devices of our users our app can't start due to this error.

I suspect this is due to too long name. We'll try to make it shorter.

Are there any other possible reasons for this error?

Comment: Does the user have sufficient permission to create the path passed to `QLocalServer::listen`?

Comment: This is most likely a bug https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-42139

Comment: Well, we do not use path, just name.